# is "get" the right prefix for a service's method that queries a DB?

Tags: java, naming-conventions, naming

I'm writing a method that given a product, returns for each country the number of sales. I named it `getNumOfSalesByCountry()`.

To me, the word "get" relates to a getter of a bean and not to a function that makes a query to a DB.

Can you suggest better names? (Or you think the name is valid)

Thanks

Comment: In frameworks like spring they uses *find*. But if it is better is *Opinion-based*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name it something like `retrieveNumOfSalesByCountry()`, but I think `getNumOfSalesByCountry()` is good too.

Comment: `retrieve` is nice. What do you prefer for your own projects?

Comment: I have no methods performing DB queries, but methods bringing me some data, details etc. I call `getThisAndThat()`